# How I can get attribute from queryset using prefetch_related in Django?

Tags: django

I have following model and extracted queryset using prefetch_related as below.

```
queryset = Light.objects.filter(
    certificate__name="A").prefetch_related('zone__namingzone'
)
```

From this queryset, I want to get following data set.

```
{"naming1":lpd1,"naming2":lpd2...}
```

However, when I try to extract attribute from queryset as below, I get `create_reverse_many_to_one_manager`

```
for i in queryset:
    print (i.zone.namingzone)
```

What I want to get is naming attribute in naming table. Could anyone tell me how I can extract this?

**models.py**

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Zone(models.Model):
    zone=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Light(models.Model):
    certificate=models.ForeignKey(Certificate, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='certificate')
    zone=models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='lightzone')
    lpd=models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('certificate', 'zone'),)

class Naming(models.Model):
    zone=models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='namingzone')
    naming=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you traverse a FK in reverse, you end up with a manager, and multiple items on the other side. So `i.zone.namingzone` in your for loop is a manager, not a `NamingZone`. If you change your print loop to:

```
for i in queryset:
    print (i.zone.namingzone.all())
```

You should see all the naming zones for your item. You can extract the naming field from each `NamingZone` from the `queryset` as follows:

```
 queryset.values('zone__namingzone__naming')
```

You probably want to extract a few other fields from your `Light` model, like the `lpd` for instance:

```
 queryset.values('lpd', 'zone__namingzone__naming')
```

You might have a same `ldp` several times, as many times as it has naming zones.